# Can you take normal brownies across the border of the USA and the EU?

Tags: food-and-drink

I can't Google this out, everyone talks of pot brownies but these are just brownies made by a friend, diabetic and *delicious* and would love to bring a few with me on a trip. I am flying Vancouver-Los Angeles-London-Hungary-London-Coppenhagen-New York-Vancouver.

Comment: The answer is absolutely yes. I just returned from Hungary with a different brownie (check Sugar Free Monkey on Raday Street, Budapest -- I swear they have the best brownies in the world!) across more borders than anyone sane should and specifically declared I have brownies with me -- UK, USA, Canada, noone cares. I declared because it is food and better to have a [quick word about the food](https://youtu.be/1XT-SQ2DPyk) with the border official than lose my NEXUS over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you went a little too detailed with trying to find your answer, the brownies are just like any other baked goods after all. I found this [US government page](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/318/~/traveling-to-the-u.s.---bringing-baked-goods-%28i.e.-cakes%2C-cookies%2C-breads%2C-etc%29) saying:

> Generally, there are no restrictions on baked goods. The U.S. Department of Agriculture's (USDA) Animal & Plant Health Inspection Service (APHIS) has a general list of approved products of which breads, cakes, cookies, and other bakery goods are listed.

The CBP Info center corroborates:

[image: CBP Info center answers yes]

Make sure to check specific airline rules as well, but I doubt you'll have any issue bringing them.

As for the EU, [Personal food, plant and animal product imports](https://gov.uk/guidance/personal-food-plant-and-animal-product-imports), this is the UK government website but its from EU Commission Regulation (EC) No 206/2009 which was transposed into UK law by: The Trade in Animals and Related Products Regulations 2011. To quote:

> Confectionery, chocolate or cakes... are permitted from any country as long as they are for your personal consumption and do not contain fresh cream or high levels of dairy products.